# Simple SQL is not getting executed?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE QRes
(
 "QUERY_ID" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ("QR_ID"),
"SOURCE" VARCHAR2(255),
 CONSTRAINT "FHDHDHJS89" FOREIGN KEY ("QrES_ID")
  REFERENCES "DQM_QUERY" ("Q_ID") ENABLE
) TABLESPACE "USERS"
LOB ("DATA") STORE AS (
TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10
NOCACHE LOGGING);
```

The output I am getting is `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Is my SQL syntax wrong?

Comment: Does `DQM_QUERY` exists?

Comment: What happens if you try select * from DQM_QUERY

Comment: @kmb385 and YetAnUs ORA-00942: table or view does not exist this is what I get. So I guess, DQM_QUERY does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a runtime error. The syntax is fine and your statement is executed, but then it runs into a problem. The problem being in this case, that some referenced table does not exist. Looking at the statement, that can only be `DQM_QUERY`. Does it exist?

Comment: So, If create a new table DQM_QUERY and fill it with data, will it get executed ?

Comment: Yeah, but you shouldn't just do that because you want to execute this statement. The problem is that you create a foreign key in this table that references another table. I figured this would be a typing error, but now I read your response, I'm starting to doubt whether you actually need this constraint, and whether you know what you're actually trying to achieve here.